# Interface Builder - Login Username/Password field just like Skype's iphone app

Tags: iphone, user-interface

I just wonder which UI element is being used for such username/password field just like in Skype's iphone app?

[http://tinypic.com/r/34t1gr9/5 http://tinypic.com/r/34t1gr9/5](http://tinypic.com/r/34t1gr9/5)

Is it UITextField or something else? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a UITableView with style set to Grouped, one section, two rows, with a UILabel and UITextField added to each cell.